# Automake fails to detect header, despite specifying include dir

Tags: compiler-errors, header-files, autotools

I am relatively new to GNU AutoTools but was put on a large C/C++ project that uses it. My role is to fork and implement an experimental feature for [this project](https://github.com/collaboraonline/online). Edit: Link is there if you would like to look at their tree structure, but building for yourself is a bit complex. If you still want to, [look here](https://collaboraonline.github.io/post/build-code/#build-code-on-arch)

I need to update the dependencies to include gtkmm headers and libraries. The configuration was successful: gtkmm headers and libs are installed on system, PkgConfig detected the paths, autoconf set the GTKMM_CFLAGS and GTKMM_LIBS varibles to those paths.

I added the following lines:
in `configure.ac`:

```bash
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GTKMM], [gtkmm-3.0 >= 3.24.0])
```

in project root `Makefile.am`:

```bash
AM_CPPFLAGS += ${GTKMM_CFLAGS}
AM_LDFLAGS += ${GTKMM_LIBS}
```

In an arbitrary cpp source file, to test, I added the line:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>
```

When running `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make -j $(nproc)`

I expect a successful build, but instead receive error:

```
In file included from ../kit/Kit.cpp:82:
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:100:10: fatal error: glibmm.h: No such file or directory
  100 | #include <glibmm.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:2379: ../kit/unittest-Kit.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../kit/Kit.cpp:82:
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:100:10: fatal error: glibmm.h: No such file or directory
  100 | #include <glibmm.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1881: ../kit/Kit.lo] Error 1
```

Glibmm is a dependency of gtkmm, and the paths for glibmm are included with gtkmm. It successfully finds the gtkmm.h header, but within that it's unable to find the glibmm.h.

To verify: I have in `config.log`:

```bash
GTKMM_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0     /include -I/usr/include/sysprof-4 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/u     sr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/fri     bidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cloudproviders -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/lib/atkmm-1.6/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -pthread '

# ...

GTKMM_LIBS='-lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lgio-2.0 -lpangomm-1.4 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 '
```

It, I believe, shows that the compiler should have all the info to include, yet the error persists and I'm unable to build the project. If I missed something important, made a mistake, or there are other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: So is `glibmm.h` in fact present on the system?  If so, what is the full path to it?

Comment: Also, please include enough of the `make` output to show the compile command that generated those error messages.